# Inject a code into the unique function in multiple files (Sublime editor)

Tags: string, text, replace, inject

Taking the advice of Xaelias I'll modify this post, because the initial question was quite unclear and overcomplicated.

So basically I have multiple script files that need to be edited (too many of them to afford to edit them manually). What I need to do for each script file is to insert a certain code at a specific location inside each of them.

So if my script file was called foo.script, and if the code inside it was as follows:

```
cut_bar() {
    some code...
}

cut_cabbage() {
   some code...
}

...
```

Then I'd like my final look of the foo.script file to be as follows:

```
cut_bar() {
    some code...
    message msg_foo_bar
}

cut_cabbage() {
    some code...
    message msg_foo_cabbage

...
```

(**cut_** is a universal prefix shared by all those functions inside of which the code needs to be added).

Is there any way I can do this in Sublime Text editor? Or is there no other way but to develop a small program that does all of this (in which case, tips would be appreciated likewise!).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the issue is. Why don't you just copy and paste for example?

Comment: Hello Xaelias, Thanks for pointing out that my initial post was quit unclear and poorly written. I've edited it and simplified it, so hopefully now you can understand what I need. Thanks again!

Comment: What programming language is this in? Duplicate code is a bad code smell. I wouldn't try to fix something like this with the search and replace functionality of a text editor.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Stephan. Well it's a extremely simple script and those functions don't have any arguments or return values, so I'm 100% sure that everything would work perfectly if only I could do what I've described up there.

I've done 20 files manually like that and everything works fine, so yeah, the functionality of code is not to worry about, this is practically only a text-editing problem.

Comment: @Vegeta_DTX One last question and I think I will be able to help you. Do your `some code...` has a fixed length? If not, fo you always want the `messave msg_...` part to be right before the closing `}` of the `cut_...` method call?

Comment: Yes Xaelias, definitely you understood it well, basically *message msg_...* always goes right before the closing *}* of the *cut_...* method function...however as for the *some code...* it is not consistent in terms of number of lines unfortunately :( Although there is always the same function right above the *cut_...* function, it's name is always *put_item*. Thanks a lot for your effort man, I appreciate the will to help whether or not you manage to help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We'll try a first solution, which is far from perfect, but might be enough for what you want to do. If it does not work, we'll try another solution.

You want to do a search and replace (<kbd>⌥⌘F</kbd> (on mac) or `Find→Replace...`).

- Make sure that the RegEx modifier is active (`.*` on the left)
- Find What: `(?<=^cut_)(.*?)(\(\)\h*\{(?:.|\v)*?)(^\}\h*$)` (explanations below)
- Replace With: `\1\2\tmsg_foo_\1\n\3`

If it does not work as intended, maybe we'll just need to tweak a little the RegEx. Or maybe we'll need to resort to python and ST plugins!

RegEx explanation:

- `(?<=^cut_)`: we want our match to start at the beginning of a line (`^`) with `cut_` this is not captured because as you said, this is a constant, so we don't really care
- `(.*?)`: this matches the rest of the name of the method. This is captured and will be `\1`
- `(\(\)\h*\{(?:.|\v)*?)`: we stop the name capture at `()`, `\h` is for any horizontal space (spaces or tabs) that could be between the end of the name, and `{`, then we match every character and `\v` (vertical space such as new lines) (this is captured as `\2`)
- `(^\}\h*$)`: ... up until we meet a line that starts with `}`, and might have any kind of horizontal space before the end of the line (`$`), this is captured as `\3`

From there, the replace part is kind of straightforward I guess.
`\1\2\` is everything we captured but do not want to modify (the name of the method, and its body, except for the last line `}`)
Then we put what you wanted, `msg_foo_\1` which will transform into `msg_foo_bar` for example, and then put back the ending `}`

Comment: First of all, I apologize for the late reply Xaelias, and I want to thank you very much for helping me with this man! :)
It worked and I got exactly what I needed by using your approach (with a couple of minor changes, but that's due to a slight change of my goal with this).

Again, thank you a bunch man, you are a real life saver! :)